# Use one graph for multiple timeseries dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am currently creating a pandas project on stock prices using time series. I have a column stock return that has negative and positive values on the y axis. I have data for the last 5 years and am trying to compare the months of each year in the same graph but when I plot them they separate along the dates rather than overlapping (image below) :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Monthly_Return2017.plot(ax=ax)
Monthly_Return2016.plot(ax=ax)
Monthly_Return2015.plot(ax=ax)
Monthly_Return2014.plot(ax=ax)
Monthly_Return2013.plot(ax=ax).axhline(y = 1, color = "black", lw = 2)
plt.show()
```

[image: enter image helloption here]

So instead I want to have them split by months Jan-December on the x-axis.
Is there anyway I can do this keep the data as a time series.
Heres a sample of three of the dataframes.

```
    Close
Date    
2017-01-31  1.000000
2017-02-28  1.033158
2017-03-31  1.041128
2017-04-30  1.137012
2017-05-31  1.210934
2017-06-30  1.140489
2017-07-31  1.167811
2017-08-31  1.178893
2017-09-30  1.203717
2017-10-31  1.275920
2017-11-30  1.281906
2017-12-31  1.313270

Close
Date    
2016-01-31  1.000000
2016-02-29  0.939188
2016-03-31  1.002692
2016-04-30  0.932781
2016-05-31  0.990268
2016-06-30  0.931557
2016-07-31  1.034780
2016-08-31  1.032438
2016-09-30  1.046221
2016-10-31  1.055979
2016-11-30  1.020311
2016-12-31  1.038859

    Close
Date    
2015-01-31  1.000000
2015-02-28  1.044676
2015-03-31  1.025219
2015-04-30  1.010808
2015-05-31  1.000970
2015-06-30  0.979148
2015-07-31  1.176855
2015-08-31  1.163010
2015-09-30  1.144519
2015-10-31  1.337128
2015-11-30  1.396929
2015-12-31  1.427554
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, 2016 has a 29th of february, other years don't. How should they be plotted on the same scale?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm pretty sure that's because there was a leap year in 2016

Comment: Yes, I know that 2016 was a leap year. Again, how should dates from different years be plotted on the same scale? Once you answer this question, I can help you implement that.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, They would be plotted over months as line graphs, so for example on the x-axis 03-31 for 2016 would be at 1.002692 on the y-axis and 03-31 for 2017 would be at 1.041128 on the y-axis

Comment: Your problem is about the x axis, not the y axis. So where on the xaxis would `2016-03-31` be located compared to `2017-03-31`, and where would `2016-02-29` be located compared to `2017-02-28`?

Comment: they should be in the same position on the x-axis, so basically disregarding the year and plotting it as if they where different stocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create two different dataframes and forget about the dates for the plot and the time series.
something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Monthly_Return2017 = Monthly_Return2017.reset_index()
Monthly_Return2016 = Monthly_Return2016.reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Monthly_Return2017['Close'].plot(ax=ax)
Monthly_Return2016['Close'].plot(ax=ax)
```

Then you can play with xticks to put up the months.
Does it help?

Comment: Yeah that does give the correct output I want thanks, I would just rather keep it in a time series, maybe this just isn't possible!

Comment: No worries, I do not know either if it is possible to keep time series in this case. And, if you do not want to play to much with your initial dataframe, just create new ones that would only be used for the plots.